# Resteasy converting List to LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am using resteasy to send key/value pairs in between some restful web-services.

to post a list of these pairs i use this snippet

```
List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
pairs.add(new Pair("name", "Arnold"));
pairs.add(new Pair("age", "20"));

ResteasyClient resteasyClient = getClient();
ResteasyWebTarget target = resteasyClient.target(targetURI);
Invocation.Builder request = target.request();
request.post(Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
```

`Pair` is just an unannotated Class with

```
public String key,
public String value 
default constructor 
(key,value) constructor
```

The target resource an receive this via:

```
 @POST
 @Path("/metadata")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response postMetadata(List<Pair> properties) {...
```

the jax-rs resource can read the List correctly.

Now the other way is the Problem:

The Retrieval Resource is defined as:

```
@GET
@Path("/getUrl.../{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getMetadata(@PathParam("id") String id) {
data_from_hibernate = em.find(id);
...
List<Pair> properties = new ArrayList<>();
//fill List from data
return Response.ok().entity(properties).build();
```

Client side is:

```
Response response = request.get("http://getUrl.../"+id);
List<Pair> properties = response.readEntity(List.class);

logger.info("got properties != null? " +(properties!=null));
logger.info("size: "+properties.size());
logger.info("[0]" + properties.get(0));
logger.info("type: "+properties.get(0).getClass().getName());
```

The List is not null;

size is correct;

get(0) does output in a strange format: [0]{"name": "value"};

this is followed by the strange format's reason: an Exception tells me that:

> java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Pair

How is `properties` a `LinkedHashMap` at this point, or rather: a List of LinkedHashMaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without type information (when you use `readEntity`), Jackson (the underlying deserializer) will convert arbitrary JSON objects to `LinkedHashMap`.

When using `readEntity`, you provide generic type information by using [`GenericType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericType.html).

```
List<Pair> properties = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Pair>>(){});
```