# Jwts.builder().setClaims() method converts list to list of LinkedHashMaps

Tags: java, jwt

I have a method that tries to extract information from a Jwt token to instantiate a UserDetails instance from. The method looks like this:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByAuthToken(String authToken){
    Claims claims = getClaimsFromToken(authToken);
    return JwtUserFactory.create(
            claims.get(CLAIM_KEY_USER_ID, Long.class),
              ....
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>claims.get(CLAIM_KEY_GRANTED_AUTHORITIES, Collection.class),
    );
```

Despite explicitly casting the list value from `CLAIM_KEY_GRANTED_AUTHORITIES` to `(List<GrantedAuthority>)` it still converts the list to a linked hashmap.

I've read here that when the type is not defined Jackson automatically converts a list to a linked hashmap. [Resteasy converting List to LinkedHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961130/resteasy-converting-list-to-linkedhashmap)
The thread is about resteasy but i think the same thing is happening in my code.
In this thread [Class cast exception in JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964955/class-cast-exception-in-jwt) I've read that Jackson is also used for determining data types when extracting data from a jwt token.

The point is that i am declaring a type, namely `List.class`. Thats as specific as i can give it because `List<GrantedAuthority>.class` results in a compile error. When i log the content of the list in the console it looks like this:

`[{authority=ROLE_USER}, {authority=ROLE_ADMIN}]`

How can i prevent Jackson from implicitly converting the GrantedAuthorityList to a List of LinkedHashMap and avoid a class cast exception?

I am using jjwt version 0.9.0

`<dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>`

Thank you

EDIT: Heres the getClaimsFromToken method

```
public Claims getClaimsFromToken(String token) {
    Claims claims;
    try {
        claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        claims = null;
    }
    return claims;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after doing some more research i've found out that there is no solution in my case. According to Baeldung https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array jackson will convert custom object lists to LinkedHashMap lists. There is a way around this using jackson ObjectMapper together with TypeReference, but that only works when the custom object has a default no-args constructor, which mine doesn't.

So my work around is this:

```
convertListOfLinkedHashMapsToSimpleGrantedAuthorityList(objectMapper.convertValue(claims.get(CLAIM_KEY_GRANTED_AUTHORITIES, ArrayList.class),
                        new TypeReference<List<LinkedHashMap<String, SimpleGrantedAuthority>>>() { }));

    private Set<? extends GrantedAuthority> convertListOfLinkedHashMapsToSimpleGrantedAuthorityList(List<LinkedHashMap<String, SimpleGrantedAuthority>> linkedHashMapList){
        return linkedHashMapList.stream().flatMap(linkedHashMap -> linkedHashMap.values().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

Hope it will help anyone